# Perl - Best way to establish an SFTP connection on windows

Tags: perl, sftp, put

I need to put files in a remote directory using SFTP on a Windows machine. I've tried `Net::SFTP::Foreign` though I can't use it because it needs `IO::Pty` which is not available on Windows machine. What's the best/simplest way to do this?

**Update With Requested Info:**

Here are the versions I'm using:

`Net::SFTP::Foreign` : v 1.89

`Net::SSH2` : v 0.69

`Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Net_SSH2` : v 0.09

and here is the gist of my code:

```
$ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh2->connect($host) || die "connect failed";
$ssh2->auth_password($user, $pass) || die "password auth failed";
$sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(ssh2 => $ssh2,
                                   backend => 'Net_SSH2');
$sftp->error and
  die "Unable to stablish SFTP connection: ". $sftp->error;
```

Right now I'm just trying to establish a connection. I will need to put files on the server. The erro I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Net::SSH2::timeout(ss, timeout) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH2.pm line 111, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred way to use [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign) in Windows is probably to use the [Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Net_SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Net_SSH2) backend (**update**: a Perl module available from CPAN) which uses [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2) under the hood (which is already included with Strawberry Perl, **update**: otherwise, you will need to build and install libssh2 yourself which sometimes is not as easy as it should be).

Another option is to [tell](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#ssh_cmd-=%3E-%5C@sshcmd) `Net::SFTP::Foreign` to use the `plink` command to run the SSH connection (search for `plink` on the module docs). **Update**:`plink` is part of the `PuTTY` application distribution, a very popular SSH client that may be already installed in that machine.

Finally you can also try using [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Any) which provides its own backend for `Net::SFTP::Foreign` and can run on top of several SSH clients and modules... but it is still in beta!

Comment: Are all these solutions Windows friendly? Will I need to install any misc modules? Or do they all use basic perl modules? I'm not authorized to be installing 3rd party software on the machine which is why I picked up perl.

Comment: Yes, those solutions are Windows specific. See my updates above.

Comment: When I attempt to use your first solution I'm getting a weird error before it dies: `Usage: Net::SSH2::timeout(ss, timeout) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH2.pm line 111, <STDIN> line 1.` Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: @CoryKleiser: I can't reproduce that error. Could you post your script code and tell us the module versions you are using (`Net::SFTP::Foreign`, `Net::SSH2` and `Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Net_SSH2`)?

Comment: I believe I added all the necessary information. Please let me know if you need any other updates.

Comment: It looks as if you had a broken installation of `Net::SSH2` mixing code from several versions. Could you reinstall `Net::SSH2` running `cpan Net::SSH2` and try your script again?

Comment: when I try to run that command it just tells me `Net::SSH2 is up to date (0.69)`

Comment: @CoryKleiser: You can force the installation using `cpan -fi Net::SSH2`.

Comment: I reinstalled `Net::SSH2` and it is throwing the same error.

Comment: Could you search for files named `SSH2.xs.dll` in your system and post here the listing? Also, could you search and send me (salva@cpan.org) a file named `SSH2.c` inside a directory whose name starts by `Net-SSH2-0.69`?

Comment: Never mind, I installed it on a different machine and everything is working fine. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

I have several cross-platform scripts that are using Net::SFTP::Foreign using plink on windows and openssh on linux and it works great. Windows is using the latest strawberry perl release.

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    host=> $server,
    ssh_cmd => $plink, #Contains full path to plink or path to ssh
    user=> $user,
    more => ['-i', $keyfile],
    stderr_discard => 1,
);
```

The only thing about using the plink backend is that you have to first manually establish a connection using psftp or Putty gui so it stores the trust confirmation in the registry. After that it is good to go from the script.

The nice thing is you can just have the actual path to ssh or to plink defined in a system level config file and the script just reads what is needed on that particular platform. ie (...\bin\Putty\plink.exe or /usr/bin/ssh )

Not a pure Perl solution, but has been very robust. I don't see IO::Pty on any of my windows boxes so no dependency there for plink.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. The problem is that I am not able to download putty on the windows machine I'm running them on. Fortunately salva's first option worked for me.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working. The plink.exe doesn't have to be 'installed' and can exist in the same directory as the script you will be uploading too.

Comment: Interesting. I’ll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is actually SSH with a wrapper to simulate the FTP like commands, so a `mdir` is actually a `ssh 'ls /path/to/dir'`.

While there might be a Perl SFTP package that avoids `IO::Pty`, you might get to your solution much faster by just translating the "FTP" commands into their ssh / scp equivalents and looking at `Net::SSH`

--- Adding an Example as requested ---

```
#!/bin/env perl

use Net::OpenSSH ();

my $connection = Net::OpenSSH->new('somehost.com', user => 'myuser', password => 'mypassword' );
my @ls = $connection->capture("ls");
printf "remote listing is %s\n", join(', ', @ls);
```

This should list the files to your console.

You mentioned not having IO::Pty because it is not available for a windows machine.  Perhaps you should be attempting to install IO::Pty::Easy.  Note that `Net::OpenSSH` uses `IO::Pty` too, but that should be possible to do on windows, provided you also install `Glib` as indicated in this post http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=856863

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps I should just do it via SSH. Do you know of any good resources about using SSH for perl that you could point me to? I've looked but the ones I find are pretty vague.

Comment: @CoryKleiser Net::OpenSSH is really the one you want to use, and it also includes `sftp` command support.  Yes, it requires `IO::Pty` but according to the link above, you should be able to use `Glib` to get IO::Pty working for Windows.

Comment: @CoryKleiser PS.  I tested the above snipped of code (with real values) against one of my systems.  It will work.  Getting it to work on Windows with the `Glib` will probably be the bigger challenge.

Comment: Do you know if `Net::SSH::Perl;` is safe for Windows? Sorry if that's a stupid question. I just started using perl less than a week ago and also use unix overwhelmingly.

Comment: @CoryKleiser I know that Net::SSH::Perl is very old and not maintained properly.  It failed to connect to my remote machine in testing; because, it was not updated to accommodate changes made to the SSH protocol some years back.  That means you'll get a protocol error using it to connect to modern remote hosts.  Net::SSH requires a `ssh` command line.  The one I used as an example is an up-to-date maintained version.  As far as Windows?  I don't use Windows anymore, so I'm in the dark there; but, you'll have SSH issues with some of the other versions.

Comment: That's wrong. SFTP is not a wrapper for SSH commands. SFTP is a fully binary protocol that uses SSH channels as the transport layer!

Comment: @CoryKleiser: Net::SSH::Perl used to be not well maintaned, but the situation has improved in the last years with a new maintainer. Now it supports most recent algorithms. On the other hand, it is still hard to install and `Net::SFTP` has lots of quirks.